# how to exclude store in clipper theme wordpress code php

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I need your help, I have exlude store in clipper theme how can I do. my code is not working, please help

```
$cat_related = query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    APP_TAX_CAT => $string_array, 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'category__not_in' => $store_id // this is STORE ID

) );
```

please I wait your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put your category id's  in an array format.  Like the below one.

```
$cat_related = query_posts( array(
'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
'post_status' => 'publish',
APP_TAX_CAT => $string_array, 
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
'paged' => $paged,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'category__not_in' => array (   $store_id )// this is STORE ID
 ) );
```

Comment: thanks, but not working, please other answer

Comment: the above one is working code for me. i am not sure. what is there in ur code file. can you copy paste the whole code here in it.

Comment: some other part of the code can affect it.